# Dependence of font-weight on font-size

Tags: css, sass, fonts, font-size

I am facing a problem that my font weight depends on the font size

Below code doesn't work

```
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 500;
```

Below code works

```
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: 500;
```

Figma has no problem with this. what could be the CSS-problem?

Comment: Combinations of size and font may not be valid for some fonts. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight) for example. Also,  providing the relevant html might be helpful and any other css affecting the selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the antialiasing of the text. It can be an issue of the font itself, if it is not optimized for smaller text for example. Or it's because of the  If it is optmized, it could be a problem of the generel font rendering. MacOS tend to make fonts bigger then they are. Set `font-smoothing` to prevent this behavior.

```css
body {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

Here is an example (and mixin for Sass):
https://codepen.io/macx/pen/gOMgKd